# How can I initialize a *char using user input?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Initializing a string in `C#` is as easy as this:

```
string str = Console.Read();
```

with this method, I don't need to know the size of the string which the user enters. But I cannot find a way like this in C++. I want my string to be defined as `char *input`, **and I don't want to know the size of the string**.

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: use `std::string`. No need for `char*`

Comment: It is a bit strange that in C#, you want to use string, but in C++, you don't want to use std::string, which is the preferred way of working with strings.  In that case, the code would be `std::string stringInput; getline(std::cin, stringInput);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use C++'s [string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) type?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string foo;
    std::cin >> foo;
    std::cout << foo << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ has a string class which works much like C#'s string. So use it. :)

`char*` is not a string. It's just the closest you get if you're working in C.

So, `#include <string>`, and then use `std::string` instead of `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::cin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream):

```
std::string str;
std::cin >> str;
```